# C++ template class with template class member

Tags: c++, class, templates

What is the current syntax for writing a template member class parameter inside a template class.

This is what I been trying to do:

```
template <class T>
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node(); // constructor 
        Node(const Node<T> &);           // copy constructor 
        ~Node();             // destructor
        T value;
        Node *next;
    };


template <class T> 
class Linked_list
{
public:
    Linked_list(); // constructor 
    Linked_list(const Linked_list<T> &); // copy constructor 
    ~Linked_list();             // destructor
    T pop();
    void push(T value);
    T top();
    bool is_empty();
    void clear();

private:
    Node<T> *head; // COMPILER ERROR
};
```

Why this is a compiler error?

```
Node<T> *head; // COMPILER ERROR
```

Comment: It isn't. GCC compiles it just fine with `-ansi -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: "Doctor, I'm sick"... "Tell me your symptoms, then"... "I'm sick !!!" http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: both Node and Linked_list are in one source file?

Comment: @SirDarius lol, it says" syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

Comment: maybe that's the issue, show us the real source file structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps when you call:

```
Node<T> *head;
```

T is not an object type, and it doesn't know how to construct that. Try:

```
Node<std::string> *head;
```

or something like that. T is not an object type, it is just like a variable name, except it is actually a variable type within the class Node and LinkedList.